# The best way to save and edit User Information within my Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save and store a user's picture, name, contact information and company address. I want the user to add and edit his information at his convenience.

I wonder what will be the best possible way to do this?

Can we do this through sharedpreference? How about internal storage? Or will it be SQLite? I am not so sure which data storage will work best since i am only saving the user's information. It will not be a list or directory.

And if you can share sample codes and projects, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you are storing the picture, I would go for a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sqlite for better persistence. You will find that the user clearing cache will not affect the saved values.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will user sqlite.

Comment: i am thinking about clearing cache , if you clear cache nothing happen to SharedPreferences . But if you clear application data your sharedpreferences will delete and your user will logout. You can try this in Facebook android app like in picture : http://www.imgim.com/unspecified.png

Comment: You are right Yasin. I did not think about that. Clearing application data will wipe out all data including those stored in your internal storage. It will make sense to use sqlite then.

Answer (score 1):

If you store picture in `Base64` format you can use SharedPreferences . If you want to store images etc. i will suggest you to use `Sqlite`. Generally search for `Sqlite` and `SharedPreferences` will help you:

Sqlite tutorial : [Sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Shared preferences working like key, value pairs: [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: Thank you Yasin. I will use Sqlite. I might store pictures in other formats beside base64.

Comment: yes in general sqlite better for support different extensions

Answer (score 1):

You can store user data with storage option in android [shared preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [sqlite database](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

preferable way is to store User information like password or such data in encryption mode

for multiuser api 17 supports [User Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html)